# How to getline() twice on same line in C++?

Tags: c++, getline

I have a file and I want to store the first part of a line until a ',' is reached, then store the remaining end of the line into another variable. Currently, it skips half the lines. For example this is three lines of my file:

```
021200725340,Scotch Removable Clear Mounting Squares - 35 Ct
041520035646,Careone Family Comb Set - 8 Ct
204040000000,Plums Black
```

My code only stores half of the lines:

```
while(getline(file, upc)){ 
    getline(file, upc, ',');        
    getline(file, description); 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you `getline()` without delimiter and split on ',' yourself?

Answer (score 5):

> My code only stores half of the lines:

The call to `getline` inside the conditional of the `while` statement is responsible for that.

Change your code to:

```
while( getline(file, upc, ',') && getline(file, description) )
{
   // Use the data.
}
```